# Get informative stack trace in node-pg

Tags: node.js, database, typescript, postgresql, node-postgres

I am using `node-pg` with typescript.

I have a getPool utility from the doc https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling

```
export const getPool = (config?: PoolConfig) => {
  const pool = new Pool(config);
  pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
    console.error('Unexpected error on idle client', err);
    process.exit(-1);
  });
  return pool;
};
```

I use it like this in an async/await context

```
const pool = getPool();
await pool.query('my sql query here...');
```

When I have an invalid SQL query I get this kind of error:

```
error: null value in column "foo" violates not-null constraint

  at Parser.parseErrorMessage (node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:357:11)
  at Parser.handlePacket (node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:186:21)
  at Parser.parse (node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:101:30)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
```

Note: I would understand if it was the `pool.on('error')`'s callback that stole my stack trace, but the errors are not prefixed with `Unexpected error on idle client`

Notice in the stack trace there is no line that points to a file in my codebase.

**My problem is, I have hundereds of queries in my codebase, and I would like to be able to trace the line that called the failing `pool.query()`. This would help a lot to find which query triggered the error.**

Expected :

```
error: null value in column "foo" violates not-null constraint

  at ...
  at mycodebase/src/myfile.ts:42
```

Comment: I have the same issue and would like to know the answer

Comment: I ended up using Prisma to connect to my database.

Comment: I think you could use attach the error handler on pool like 
`pool.on('error', (e)=>{logger.error(e); throw e;})` , this would log the exact error and for asyc/await try/catch shall catch any error which are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I use dirty hack (patch `Pool.prototype`), but it works for me:

```
const originalPoolQuery = Pool.prototype.query;
Pool.prototype.query = async function query(...args) {
    try {
        return await originalPoolQuery.apply(this, args);
    } catch (e) {
        // All magic is here. new Error will generate new stack, but message will copyid from e
        throw new Error(e)
    }
}

// After hack create pool and good luck
const pool = new Pool({})

await pool.query('SELECT * FROM ...')
```

Stacktrace in this case will be more informative.

I think that `pool.on('error', cb)` is not for catching query errors, it for connection errors (i am not sure)

Comment: That's a great step forward, I can see the stack traces and the file it comes from -  but for some reason the line numbers of the stack trace are incorrect or offset

Comment: Maybe it's cause TypeScript? I didn't see any row number mismatch

Comment: You can also use `catch(e) {Error.captureStackTrace(e); throw e;}` in order to retain the other properties of the error while accomplisihng the same thing. I made a PR to add this to node-pg https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/2983

Answer (score 1):

A recent update on node-postgres provides accurate stacktrace.

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/2983